# Use one account in 1000 devices

Tags: android

we have a business where we have developed an android platform in 1,000 devices inside taxis.

For this, we need to login 1,000x into play store.

We have used one account so far (test@gmail.com) but it seems that often it automatically logs out on many devices, even though it should permanently be logged in, to receive software updates.

We currently tried to log in around 80 devices, but about 40 of them get logged out of Play Store.

Is the issue that we can't login multiple devices with 1 account or what can be the problem?

Are we able to use one account and keep them logged in on all devices?

Comment: This question should go to google forums!

Comment: Ask google, we just program the stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related and should be posted on Google forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Google Play Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/intl/en_US/about/play-terms.html)

> Limits on access on Devices. Google may from time to time place limits
>   on the number of Devices and/or software applications you may use to
>   access Content (for more information, please visit the Help link for
>   the relevant Content within Google Play). Google may record and store
>   the unique device identifier numbers of your Devices in order to
>   enforce such limits.

Comment: just use google.com to help you fix your google issues :3